# Find Loan Amount using parameters ROI and Tenure

Tags: finance

I'm trying to find out Loan Amount taken for my 1-year old purchased bike from the bank.

I know my EMI, ROI (Rate of interest) and Tenure.

EMI = 2924, 
Tenure = 24 Months, 
ROI = 10.5%

Note: This is Flat Rate not Diminishing interest rate.

Please help me with the formula to find out the Loan amount taken.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use the equation $$F = A*\dfrac {(1+\frac {i}{m})^t - 1}{\frac {i}{m}(1+\frac {i}{m})^m}$$ where $P = \text {total loan amount} \\ A = \text {EMI (monthly payment)} \\ i = \text {interest} \\ m = \text {type of installment (12 = monthly, 1 = annually)} \\ t = \text {tenure (time)}$

Comment: You´re completely off the track.

Comment: Yup...missed it by a country mile.

Comment: Funny. I appreciate that you´ve corrected it.

Comment: The original equation I used what for simple interest.  I used your example to get the correct equation.