# Find the loan amount borrowed

Tags: finance

I am working on the EMI calculator module as part of the current banking project. I find answers for calculating simple interest, EMI, and even tenure but not able to find a formula to calculate the total amount borrowed. I found the below formula to calculate what I want but that is incorrect

source: Find Loan Amount using parameters ROI and Tenure

Here are the loan details,

Monthly EMI: 32530,

Loan tenure: 5 years,

Interest: 10.90

Total loan amount: ?

What is the formula to find the total loan amount?

What i have tried,

[image]

Here is the formula i have taken from the below source,

[image]

Here is the [source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3063602/find-loan-amount-using-parameters-roi-and-tenure)

Here is the problem on [editor](https://quickmath.com/#c=solve&v1=32530*%255Cfrac%257B%255Cleft%25281%2B%255Cfrac%257B0.109%257D%257B12%257D%255Cright%2529%255E%257B60%257D-1%257D%257B%255Cfrac%257B0.109%257D%257B12%257D%255Cleft%25281%2B%255Cfrac%257B0.109%257D%257B12%257D%255Cright%2529%255E%257B12%257D%257D)

Comment: It works with your formula. You should get 1.5 million. But notice that you have $5\cdot 12$ months.

Comment: I tried with 60 but it doesn't work

Comment: The problem is linked to a editor

Comment: I've written an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general formula is

$$PV=r\cdot \frac{\left(1+\frac{i}{m}\right)^{n\cdot m}-1}{\frac{i}{m}\cdot \left(1+\frac{i}{m}\right)^{n\cdot m}},$$

where $m=12 \, \textrm{(monthly)}, i=0.109$, $n=5$=number of years and $r=32530$ is the EMI (equated monthly installment). With the given numbers the term becomes

$$PV=32530\cdot \frac{\left(1+\frac{0.109}{12}\right)^{5\cdot 12}-1}{\frac{0.109}{12}\cdot \left(1+\frac{0.109}{12}\right)^{5\cdot 12}}=1.4996... \, \textrm{million}\approx 1.5 \, \textrm{million}$$

[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=32530%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac%7B%281%2B%5Cfrac%7B0.109%7D%7B12%7D%29%5E%7B5%5Ccdot%2012%7D-1%7D%7B%5Cfrac%7B0.109%7D%7B12%7D%5Ccdot%20%281%2B%5Cfrac%7B0.109%7D%7B12%7D%29%5E%7B5%5Ccdot%2012%7D%7D) is the result of an online-calculator.

Comment: Thanks, calculus.

Comment: The Chinese guy got mad and downvoted my question

Comment: Please upvote my question

Comment: @anonymous Done.